# Implicit Fact division and Dimension Usage

Tags: ssas

I have a star schema with Implicit Fact division as shown in Figure 5 at http://www.information-management.com/infodirect/20020308/4858-1.html?pg=2.

My question is how do I set up the Dimension Usage?  My first thought was to set up 3 Referenced Relationships (CustomerGroup to InvoiceItemFacts, GroupToCustomer to CustomerGroup, CustomerDimension to GroupToCustomer), but when I try this I get the message "A loop was found in the data source view at the 'dbo_CustomerGroup' table".

Update:

I have found that if I create a Regular Relationship between GroupToCustomer and InvoiceItemFacts (effectively by passing the CustomerGroup table because I already have the Customer Group Key) I can get some results.  However, when I browse the cube and display the InvoiceItemFacts by Customer, the InvoiceItemFacts only display on the first Customer in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupToCustomer looks to be a "Fact-less Fact Table", so you would create a measuregroup on that, doesn't need to be visible to the end users, then do a Many-Many join via that fact in the dimension usage tab.

It's a little complicated by the extra table in the way, but that should be the approach.